# why do we need vuex rather than just simple global objects

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have this questions all around my head for really a long time. When I use vue for frontend, every time I need shared data among different components, I would choose vuex with no doubt. However, the truth is I really dont know why I use it. Lots of times, I think it would be enough to just define a global object in main.js. So, what is the reason why choose vuex over defining a global object in the outside?

In the vuex documentation, it is said Vuex has two advantages over plain global objects.
[image]

and also I read this

> Vuex helps us deal with shared state management with the cost of more concepts and boilerplate. It's a trade-off between short term and long term productivity.
>   If you've never built a large-scale SPA and jump right into Vuex, it may feel verbose and daunting. That's perfectly normal - if your app is simple, you will most likely be fine without Vuex. A simple store pattern may be all you need. But if you are building a medium-to-large-scale SPA, chances are you have run into situations that make you think about how to better handle state outside of your Vue components, and Vuex will be the natural next step for you. There's a good quote from Dan Abramov, the author of Redux:

So can anyone list some examples that vuex is really do the job rather than just have a plain global object in the main.js?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Vuex is an implementation of the Flux data flow pattern. You should read up on its reasons for existing and advantages ~ https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview

Comment: These two advantages actually explain challenges that you will face when doing this with plain object, you won't go far without reactivity.